# Javascript: How do you check if the string contains either letter/number of both?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex, reactjs

I am trying to figure out whether the string contains either letter/number or both.

Right now, I am using

```js
/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/gi.test(newFolderName)
```

That returns true if the text only contains string, ex. "abcd" or only contains numbers, ex. "1234".

That regex doesn't seem to work for the string that contains both string and number. ex. "abcd 1234".

** I would like to allow spaces between letters and numbers.

Could anyone please tell me the regex that can fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be a space between `abcd` and `1234`

Comment: that works for me with `1a`.

Comment: Be careful that spaces are characters too

Comment: @Kaddath Okay, I see. How do you allow spaces between letters and numbers?

Comment: @Eunicorn Add the space character to the set: `^[\w ]+$`

Comment: @Eunicorn to allow every white-spaces (tabs, etc) you can use `\s`, for space only, just add a space: `/^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+$/gi`

Comment: Do you want `letters`, `spaces`, `numbers` like `abc 123` or any order like `123 abc` or `abc def` or `123 123` or `a 1 b 2` are all these possibilities correct or not? Please, edit your question and add test cases with expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regexp:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z ]+$
```

Note the whitespace at the end of the sets.

Keep in mind that \w matches all the numbers and all the letters. So you could be more concise, as suggested by ctwheels, by using this syntax:

```
^[\w ]+$
```

Comment: the problem is now you're also implicitly adding tabs, newlines, and a bunch of other whitespace characters that may or may not be acceptable in this instance.

Comment: This regex allows a string with only spaces like `     `

Answer (score 0):

To require at least 1 letter and 1 number and allow spaces,
use this -

`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d ]+$/`